# How to search file with pattern

Tags: php, file, search

I have a folder with many file , and i need to perform a deletion with certain file 
and those file have a pattern like

```
messages.bm.inc.php 
messages.cn.inc.php 
messages.en.inc.php
```

Those file are dynamically created , but the pattern is there

Before this i normally delete my file with below code , and repeat it

```
$filename="messages.en.inc.php";

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
}
```

Now i having a more dynamic situation , i need search through those file with the patern and delete it , please suggest a way to do , thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `glob()`?

Comment: `unset()` does not delete a file, you realise right?

Comment: 'search through those file with the patern'. Do you mean search it using 'en' or 'cn'?

Comment: hey sorry i mean unlink , corrected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$files = glob("path_to_your_files/messages.*.inc.php ");
array_map('unlink', $files);
```

By `glob` you will get all your files from folder by specified pattern, `array_map` will implement `unlink` function for array of matched files.

Comment: super short implementation with array_map!

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (glob("messages.*.inc.php") as $filename) {
    unlink($filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP [glob()](http://php.net/glob) function to get the list of the files by pattern and delete using the loop.